# Exception when creating availability set in Resource Group with name that starts with '_'

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

In some testing or our app that creates resources via the Resource Manager APIs, we have noticed that the ARM APIs are throwing an exception when you create an Availability Set in a Resource Group that has a name that starts with an '_'.  The Resource Group is valid and was created in the Azure portal.

Here is the error we get:

`Cloud Exception Details: Code - InvalidParameter; Message - The entity name 'resourceGroupName' is invalid according to its validation rule: ^[^_\W][\w-._]{0,79}(?<![-.])$.; Target - resourceGroupName.Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: The entity name 'resourceGroupName' is invalid according to its validation rule: ^[^_\W][\w-._]{0,79}(?<![-.])$.`

Answer (score 0):

It is a known issue, MSFT has replied to this issue, you could wait for fixing the problem or use another resource group, refer to this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6a4d1f93-9ce0-49c0-93a3-7d9f7fe67f1b/bug-azure-resource-groups-validation-rules-not-working).

> The validation rules in the Compute Resource Provider will be aligned with ARM’s sometime next year. Until then, workaround is to avoid leading parentheses in RG names. You can also move resources to a different RG.

Comment: Man it has almost been two years and the issue still exists

Comment: @MichaelSabin Yes, I recommend you to use another resouce group. Besides, you could mark it for others to refer.